# Nhibernate Cannot delete the child object

Tags: nhibernate

I know it has been asked for many times, i also have found a lot of answers on this website, but i just **cannot** get out this problem.

Can anyone help me with this piece of code?

Many thanks.

Here is my parent mapping file

```
<set name="ProductPictureList" table="[ProductPicture]" lazy="true" order-by="DateCreated" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
  <key column="ProductID"/>
  <one-to-many class="ProductPicture"/>
</set>
```

Here is my child mapping file

```
<class name="ProductPicture" table="[ProductPicture]" lazy="true">
<id name="ProductPictureID">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
<property name="ProductID" type="Int32"></property>
<property name="PictureName" type="String"></property>
<property name="DateCreated" type="DateTime"></property>
</class>
```

Here is my c# code

```
        var item = _productRepository.Get(productID);

        var productPictrue = item.ProductPictureList
            .OfType<ProductPicture>()
            .Where(x => x.ProductPictureID == productPictureID);

        // reomve the finding item
        var ok =  item.ProductPictureList.Remove(productPictrue);

        _productRepository.SaveOrUpdate(item);
```

ok is false value and this child object is still in my database.

Comment: Where is the code for `_productRepository.SaveOrUpdate`?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but could be because you have defined ProductID as a property of ProductPicture, I assume this is the PK from the Product class.  You don't need to add this again, it will be created by the relationship.

Comment: thanks for the help, do you mean i can remove the ProductID from my mapping, class and database, and this relationship will still be there?

Comment: I mean remove it from mapping file for ProductPicture

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your use of `table="[ProductPicture]"` in the set tag is right.

The one-to-many tag already establishes the link between ProductPictureList and ProductPicture. 
I think the table attribute is generally for using a separate relationship table when modelling many-to-may relationships.

From nhibernate.info [Doc](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html#collections-mapping):

> table (optional - defaults to property name) the name of the
>   collection table (not used for one-to-many associations)

[And](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html#collections-ofvalues):

> A collection table is required for any collection of values and any
>   collection of references to other entities mapped as a many-to-many
>   association